# Triviality of map $(\Sigma \theta)^*$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

We know that there is a cofibration sequence
$$S^{4n+1}\xrightarrow{\theta}\Sigma^{4m-1} Q_{n-m} \rightarrow \Sigma^{4m-1} Q_{n-m+1} \rightarrow S^{4n+2}\xrightarrow{\Sigma\theta}\Sigma^{4m} Q_{n-m}.$$
How to show the map $$(\Sigma\theta)^*\colon\widetilde {KSp}^{-2} (\Sigma^{4m} Q_{n-m}) \rightarrow \widetilde {KSp}^{-2} (S^{4n+2})\cong \mathbb{Z}$$ is zero,
where $m$ and $n$ are two positive integers such that $m<n$, and $Q_{n-m}$ is the symplectic quasi-projective space of rank $n-m$?

Comment: TeX note: instead of `\overset{#1}\rightarrow`, you can use `\xrightarrow{#1}` (which grows with its argument). Compare, for example, $\overset{\Sigma\theta}\rightarrow$ `\overset{\Sigma\theta}\rightarrow` to $\xrightarrow{\Sigma\theta}$ `\xrightarrow{\Sigma\theta}`.  I have edited accordingly.